# map not a function using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, function, dictionary, react-hooks

i'm trying to populate a select bar with a name from an API call. I Have created my hook, also useEffect for its side effects, and passed the data down the return. its giving me map is not a function error. my variable is an empty array but the setter of the variable is not assigning the value to my variable. How can i clear the map not a function error ? i have attached my snippet. Thanks.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchIngredients = async (url) => {
      try {
        let res = await axios.get(url);
        setIngredients(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIngredients([]);
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchIngredients(
      "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v2/1/search.php?i=vodka"
    );
  }, []);


  const displayIngredients = ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
    setIngredients(ingredient.name);
    return <option key={ingredient.name}>{ingredients}</option>;
  });

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <label>
        By ingredient:
        <select>{displayIngredients}</select>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar
```

Comment: Can you put `console.log(res.data)` right before `setIngredients(res.data);` and post what you see here?

Comment: `ingredients` is retrieved async, this means in the first render it is undefined until the response from axios returns. You will need to check if the data has been returned before using `map`.

Comment: Aside from several problems with your code, I am afraid there is a more fundamental issue - you're not properly handing what your API actually returns. 1. It returns an object, not an array. 2. The data does not use the `name` attribute anywhere. So I would pull up that API link in your browser and really examine the returned data's content first.

Answer (score 2):

First, here

```
setIngredients(res.data);
```

change `res.data` to `res.ingredients` (the response object doesn't have `data` property). Then you'll face another bug,

```
const displayIngredients = ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
    setIngredients(ingredient.name);
//...
```

First, `ingredient.name` is undefined, and second, it probably would be a string if it existed. Just ditch the `setIngredients` call here.

Comment: This is incorrect. An axios response DOES have the prop `data` in it. The problem the OP is having is that their API call returns an object with the attribute `ingredients`. As such, this is what they need `setIngredients(res.data.ingredients);`. https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v2/1/search.php?i=vodka

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `displayIngredients` as a variable typeof array (By directly affecting the *array.map()* result). You need it to be a *function that return an array* as follow :

```
const displayIngredients = () => ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
    // Do not erase your previous values here
    setIngredients(previousState => [...previousState, ingredient.name]);
    // Changed it here as well, seems more logic to me
    return <option key={ingredient.name}>{ingredient.name}</option>; 
  });
```

You should also wait for the API call to end before to display your select to prevent a blank result while your data load (If there is a lot). The easiest way to do that is returning a loader while the API call is running :

```
if(!ingredients.length) {
 return <Loader />; // Or whatever you want
}

return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <label>
        By ingredient:
        <select>{displayIngredients}</select>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
```